# How can i put the input up into the textField?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Im doing a form for can upload a description into my db as a favorite option, The question is how can i make text input start from the beggining of the TextInput component?

Here's the snippet of the code implemented:

```
<View style={{backgroundColor:'white',height:width.height-175,paddingTop:10, alignItems:'center'}}>
            <TextInput style={{height: width.height-180, 
                               borderColor: 'gray', 
                               borderWidth: 1, 
                               borderRadius:4,
                               width:width.width-50,
                               paddingLeft:30, 
                               paddingRight:30,
                               fontFamily:'NunitoSans-Light',position:'absolute', color:'#596471', fontSize:15}} multiline = {true} label={'descripcionInput'}
                               value={this.state.descripcion}
                               onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({descripcion:text})}>
            </TextInput>
</View>
```

[App's Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xKkE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The positioning is likely centering due to the `alignItems:'center'` property in the `View` styling. Try changing that property to `flex-start`

Comment: the input marker is still in the center of the textInput componente :( , it aint worked. it just restore the position of the component in the view but doesn't work for the input into the textfield component